# How to get a brief version of a Model in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel-5

I have a Model called User, which return many properties of the users, including some arrays like 'followers'.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $appends = [
        'followers'
    ];

    public function followers()
    {
        $followers = ShortUser::join('friends', function ($join){
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'friends.user_id')->where('friends.friend', '=', $this->id);
        });

        return $followers;
    }

    public function getFollowersAttribute()
    {
        if (!$this->followers())
            return null;
        return $followers = $this->followers()->get();
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to sometimes retrieve users with all details (as it is now)

```
User::where('user_id', $user_id)
```

and sometimes to retrieve them with fewer details (only a brief), excluding, for example the property "followers", using:

```
User::where('id', $user_id)->brief()
//or
User::where('id', $user_id)->exclude(['followers'])
```

How can I achieve this?

I tried to use a scope method to set

```
$this->appends['followers']=NULL;
```

but it seems to not work, the property does not get modified.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, I decided to use this workaround. I created a new class inheriting the User class and overriding the methods that were generating the useless data.

```
class ShortUser extends User
{
    public function getFollowersAttribute()
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```